# Get the first item property with lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In C#, I'm going to use lambda expression, I have such a code

```
var item = dbContext.Products.ToList();
```

How can i get a property of Product table.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want a list of a certain property of `Product` or the property of one `Product`?

Comment: You want the product property in each item in the list or just one item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var item = dbContext.Products.FirstOrDefault().Name;
```

Comment: If the list is empty,  he will get NullReferenceException here.

Comment: In C#6 you can do `var item = dbContext.Products.FirstOrDefault()?.Name;` which will check if `Product` is null before you try to access the name property

Answer (score 1):

With Lamba expression normally you can access and read information from "list" or in this case, IQueryable objects.

With your code you can access to objects with something like this:

```
var item = dbContext.Products.FirstOrDefault();
// item may be null if products table is empty
if (item != null)
{
    // now you can access at object properties (example)
    var data = item.PropertyData;
}
```

Your question may open others way that including reflection for exploring object without well known class definition...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the property for each product with lambda expression, then you should make a lambda expression like `x => x.Prop` when you do your query

```
if (dbContext.Products != null){
    var list = dbContext.Products.ToList();
    var query = list.Select(x => x.Prop //your property will appear here...
}
```